# How can I split or replace only certain quotes with nothing? [csharp]

Tags: c#

Basically I want to remove the first and last quote in this json text but I don't know how to.

```
"{"serverToken": "798358975235895283958208564208520o45", "username": "ImSkrt", "imageUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.orderv.com/orderv_live/static/player_avatars/12039273888.1557487912.907537.jpg", "message": "Success!"}"
```

It should eventually look like this

```
{"serverToken": "798358975235895283958208564208520o45", "username": "ImSkrt", "imageUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.orderv.com/orderv_live/static/player_avatars/12039273888.1557487912.907537.jpg", "message": "Success!"}
```

I already tried replacing it but it would replace all the quotes.

```cs
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient hc2 = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://f2aa611yne.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/players/confirm/");

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> p = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            p.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("device_id", "0AF0406E-6DD1-452E-BE14-3B5A94ACE320"));
            p.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("passcode", textBox8.Text));
            p.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("phone_number", textBox4.Text));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.PostAsync("https://f2aa611yne.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/players/confirm/", new FormUrlEncodedContent(p));

            string s = await(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            Console.WriteLine(s);

            string ss = s.Replace(@"\", "");

            Console.WriteLine(ss);

            string sss = ss.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `string.Trim` as such:

```
string ss = s.Trim('\"');
```

This will clear all occurrences of quotation marks at the beginning and end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and last character of the string using substring()

```
string s = await(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

string s2 = s.Substring(1,s.length - 2);
```